# visual studio premium programs open in visual studio express?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

Will Programs in Visual Studio Premium Open in Visual Studio Express?

Answer (score 3):

There are some project types that are not supported by Visual Studio Express. For example if you created a solution containing a unit test project in Visual Studio Ultimate you will not be able to open it in Visual Studio Express. Also make sure you check the Visual Studio Editions [features comparison matrix](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison).

Comment: what about basic C++ programs? maybe a calculator or something, would I be able to open that in VS express, even though I've compiled it in premium? I'm new to this!

Comment: @John, you don't open compiled binaries in Visual Studio. You open source code projects and solutions. [Visual Studio Express C++ 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express) supports common C++ project types.

Comment: so its just basically an editor? I can import my libraries and scripts used in premium into express if necessary?

Comment: @John, it's a little more than editor. It's an IDE. It allows you more than simply editing source code. It allows you to also execute and debug source code. You should be able to open most common project types.